# MySQL partitioning a vehicle table

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I'm fairly new to partitioning, and can't seem to find a definitive answer to this.  I have a fairly large table of vehicles that I use very often.  It has a about 3 million records (for now) in it with vin, make, model, year, color, etc.

I access this table via VIN to find the vehicle info.  When I do, obviously the query takes a while, even with the VIN indexed.  I looked into partitioning since I want to use this table more often.  Also, since I access via VIN, and there's a logical order to a VIN number, I was going to partition on VIN.  But as far as I know you can't partition on a varchar.  So I'm wondering how I would approach this.

I thought about splitting the VIN into individual indexed columns, create a primary key and partition on the key? For example if a VIN were **1HGCM82633A004352** and there is logic behind this (http://www.carfax.com/vin_decoding.cfx)

```
CREATE TABLE cars(
id bigint, 
vin varchar(20),
vin_country int, -- for the first digit
vin_manuf_type varchar(2), -- manufacturing and type
vin_the_rest varchar(14) -- the rest, for demo purposes I didnt split it all  
);

ALTER TABLE cars PARTITION BY HASH(id) PARTITIONS 10;
```

Does this seem like a logical partition? Or is splitting the VIN and the partition counter productive?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Forgive me for questioning the premise of your question, but it's not certain that partitioning will help speed of access to a three megarow table. If you haven't tried easier measures like optimizing your tables, please do so before you cross the River Styx into the underworld of partitioning.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html

Comment: We optimized the tables as best we could, but it's still pretty hard to query the table.  I guess it's the nature of the beast.